# How to declare a promise variable so that i can use it anywhere before promise gets resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

i have a problem in using promise resolved code before it is resolved.

i have multiple pages which page loads first is difficult for me to say, resolved data from multiple promise is used all developers.

here is how i get resolved data from multiple promise

```
asyncCompletedPromise = Promise.all([getUserCollection(), getDefaultSettings(), getGroupUsersDetails()]).then((values) => {
  console.log('all promises are done');
  console.log(values);
  return values;
});
```

**Question:** how to make this `asyncCompletedPromise` variable as promise based so that i can use it before promise is resloved.

**here is working demo:**

```js
var asyncCompletedPromise = Promise, apiCompletedTracker = {};

function getUserCollection(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
               console.log('getUserCollection api completed');
               apiCompletedTracker['getUserCollection'] = 'completed';
               resolve({user:data});
            }
        });
    });
}

function getDefaultSettings(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('getDefaultSettings api completed');
              apiCompletedTracker['getDefaultSettings'] = 'completed';
              resolve({default:data});
            },1500);
        }
    })
   });
}

function getGroupUsersDetails(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('getGroupUsersDetails api completed');
              apiCompletedTracker['getGroupUsersDetails'] = 'completed';
              resolve({group:data});
            },2500);
        }
    })
   });
}

// when all of the above function completes i can apply 


asyncCompletedPromise = Promise.all([getUserCollection(), getDefaultSettings(), getGroupUsersDetails()]).then((values) => {
  console.log('all promises are done');
  //console.log(values);
  return values;
});


asyncCompletedPromise.then(function(values){
   console.log('variable used first time');
});


asyncCompletedPromise.then(function(values){
   console.log('variable used second time');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When i use `asyncCompletedPromise` variable before all promise `Promise.all()` is resolved code is giving error

```js
var asyncCompletedPromise = Promise, apiCompletedTracker = {};

function getUserCollection(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
               console.log('getUserCollection api completed');
               apiCompletedTracker['getUserCollection'] = 'completed';
               resolve({user:data});
            }
        });
    });
}

function getDefaultSettings(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('getDefaultSettings api completed');
              apiCompletedTracker['getDefaultSettings'] = 'completed';
              resolve({default:data});
            },1500);
        }
    })
   });
}

function getGroupUsersDetails(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('getGroupUsersDetails api completed');
              apiCompletedTracker['getGroupUsersDetails'] = 'completed';
              resolve({group:data});
            },2500);
        }
    })
   });
}

// Note below line, i want to use it somewhere before it is actually resolved
asyncCompletedPromise.then(function(values){
   console.log('called before all promises are resolved,giving error, error should not happen irrespective calling it anywhere');
});

// when all of the above function completes i can apply


asyncCompletedPromise = Promise.all([getUserCollection(), getDefaultSettings(), getGroupUsersDetails()]).then((values) => {
  console.log('all promises are done');
  //console.log(values);
  return values;
});


asyncCompletedPromise.then(function(values){
   console.log('variable used first time');
});


asyncCompletedPromise.then(function(values){
   console.log('variable used second time');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve here that would make you need to access a promise before you have defined it?

Comment: You do `promise.all` and after it completed do `then`. If you want to do something before promise completed, don't use `then`

Comment: @charlietfl, i'm working with multiple developers, who may use them before when promise is actually gets resolved, i wanted to solve that

Comment: *"before resolved"* to do what exactly? This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are also confusing the concepts of definition and resolution in the example

Comment: Any function, that will be placed after `Promise.all` will run before promise resolved (of course if it is not another promise)

Comment: @charlietfl, it is not xy problem, it is actual problem for me. i'm working for old jquery project where multiple pages are loaded. sometime calling function itself will not be executed before using it.  **Actually** i have solved this problem by using `setInterval` but i don't want to use it anymore

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with promises. You cannot use the variable before you have assigned it a value, point.

Notice that even in your first, working snippet you are using the variable before the promise that it holds is asynchronously fulfilled with the ajax responses.

Comment: i want to `asyncCompletedPromise` declare as global variable of type `promise` that is what my question is all about, even declared promise type variable is a kind of watcher , which i can use anywhere

Comment: Yes, and as with all global variables you need to put the initialisation code before the usage code. Why would it be a problem to move `asyncCompletedPromise = Promise.all([getUserCollection(), getDefaultSettings(), getGroupUsersDetails()])` to the top of your script?

Comment: now my question would be how can i `watch` on that global `asyncCompletedPromise` variable from anywhere irrespective of calling it anywhere

Comment: or you will suggest to use `setInterval` to `watch` on those data

Comment: Wait, what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Again, why can't you just put the promise initialisation at the top? Are there actually multiple scripts involved? No, you cannot/should not watch a variable.

Comment: >>>>> Yes, and as with all global variables you need to put the initialisation code before the usage code.............. <<<<<<

if i'm the only developer i can shift that code but , one of developer is getting similar kind of error as shown above, when his page loads